# Access the Product Grid Collection from the Product Edit Page

Tags: blocks, product-collection, collection-filtering, grid

I'm trying to access the product grid collection from the product edit page, so that I can find where this currently edited product resides in the product grid collection. Ultimately, I want to provide a previous and next button on the edit page. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php

class Tloc_Test_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit {
    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        /*
         * Get the product_filter param directly from the session
         */
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
        $gridFilterParams = $session->getData('productGridproduct_filter');

        if (!empty($gridFilterParams)) {
            $decodedParams = base64_decode($gridFilterParams);
            if (!empty($decodedParams)) {
                parse_str($decodedParams, $params);
                Zend_Debug::dump($params);
            }
        }

        /*
         * Get the product_filter param through the Widget_Grid block.
         */
        /** @var Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid $gridBlock */
        $gridBlock = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_grid');
        $gridBlock->setId('productGrid');
        $gridBlock->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $gridFilterParams = $gridBlock->getParam('product_filter');

        if (!empty($gridFilterParams)) {
            $decodedParams = base64_decode($gridFilterParams);
            if (!empty($decodedParams)) {
                parse_str($decodedParams, $params);
                Zend_Debug::dump($params);
            }
        }

        die('stop');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Both methods of setting `$gridFilterParams` work, but ideally I would like to use the built-in block class.

What I want to do at this point is turn the params that I have into filters on a collection. My first choice would be to have `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` do this, but I have two problems: 1) I would first need to add Columns to the class, and I'm not sure how to do that, and 2) I'm up against a number of `protected` methods.

I could use a bit more of a manual approach and build a new collection myself, and use `addAttributeToFilter` to filter the collection, but I'm not sure how well that's going to work with custom grid columns that other modules have added.

Any one have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

When on a product grid page, you can remember in the session the list of ids ( not filters) and use them later at the product edit page.

Limitations: 1) wont work for direct page access 2) need special approach for first / last  product. For example, you may remember the SQL query and not the filters.